# Simulate a fling gesture in Android ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have an Android view that I am detecting a fling gesture on to perform an operation, and I want to write some tests to verify that the gesture is working correctly. I have tried `TouchUtils.dragViewTo` and `TouchUtils.drag` (with a very small number of steps) but neither of these seem to trigger the event.

Is there a way to simulate the fling gesture?

Comment: Aren't you then testing the wrong thing? What you _would_ like to test, is the action performed when the fling gesture occurs. I assume that the fling gesture is just a simple event with an event listener attached. Inside the event listener you probably call some function - and it's _that_ function you would like to test.

Comment: I am already testing the output function but I want to know that it performs correctly with the fling gesture as it matters which direction the gesture happens in and I want to test the logic of that as the listener interprets the direction of the fling.  It just seems strange that I can interact with the view by simulating touching and dragging but none of the drag operations seem to perform a fling. I'm just wondering if I am missing something subtle

Comment: Ok, I see. Now this is just me thinking loud (and I'm not too familiar with testing in Android, so there might be problems I don't see with this approach), but if you want to test the logic of interpreting the gesture, couldn't you just put in another layer of abstraction? In your `onFling` event handler, you just pass all arguments along to your own `processFlingEvent(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)` function, which then should be easier to test?

Comment: That is an approach that would work, but then of course there is the argument that I am modifying the design to make it testable. All well and good if it's just me developing it all but if I want to delegate the writing of the UI tests to another developer then they cannot just exercise the UI instrumentation to drive the interface and perform functional tests.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is a really old question, but posting a solution which worked for me, may help others who come searching for this

```
int[] xy = new int[2];
View v = currentActivity.getCurrentFocus();
v.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
final int viewWidth = v.getWidth();
final int viewHeight = v.getHeight();
final float x = xy[0] + (viewWidth / 2.0f);
float fromY = xy[1] + (viewHeight / 2.0f);
int screenWidth = currentActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();    
//Drag from centre of screen to Leftmost edge of display
TouchUtils.drag(this, (screenWidth - 1), x,  fromY, fromY , 5); //Vary the last parameter to sdjust speed of fling
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the TouchUtils source, the problem here is that step count is just the number of touch events to generate and doesn't affect how fast they happen:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; ++i) {
        y += yStep;
        x += xStep;
        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        inst.waitForIdleSync();
    }
```

It's waiting for a sync with the app after every event, so it doesn't seem like that is happening fast enough to fling. We can see that from how the GestureDetector recognizes a fling:

```
           // A fling must travel the minimum tap distance
            final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
            velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            final float velocityY = velocityTracker.getYVelocity();
            final float velocityX = velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

            if ((Math.abs(velocityY) > ViewConfiguration.getMinimumFlingVelocity())
                    || (Math.abs(velocityX) > ViewConfiguration.getMinimumFlingVelocity())){
                handled = mListener.onFling(mCurrentDownEvent, mCurrentUpEvent, velocityX, velocityY);
            }
```

So I recommend a custom drag method that doesn't wait for syncs on each touch move event (we don't care that the UI updates with each drag move anyway, we just want to generate a fling). Something like this (not tested):

```
public static void fling(InstrumentationTestCase test, float fromX, float toX, float fromY,
        float toY, int stepCount) {
    Instrumentation inst = test.getInstrumentation();

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    float y = fromY;
    float x = fromX;

    float yStep = (toY - fromY) / stepCount;
    float xStep = (toX - fromX) / stepCount;

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, fromX, y, 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    inst.waitForIdleSync();

    for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; ++i) {
        y += yStep;
        x += xStep;
        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        //inst.waitForIdleSync();
    }

    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, fromX, y, 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    inst.waitForIdleSync();
}
```

Well, actually all I did there was comment out the waiting for idle sync in the motion event loop. Pick some reasonable values for distance travelled and step count and that should work. If it doesn't, you might need a short wait in the loop to slightly space out the events if they're coming too fast.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what your looking for,  but here is an example of a test i wrote to ensure that the fling gesture is working on a custom gallery component.

```
public void testLeftSwipe() {
    int initialSelectedItemPosition = mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition();

    Rect r = new Rect();
    mGallery.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);

    float fromX = r.centerX();
    float toX = r.centerX() - (r.width() / 4);
    float fromY = r.centerY();
    float toY = r.centerY();
    int stepCount = 10;

    TouchUtils.drag(this, fromX, toX, fromY, toY, stepCount);

    assertTrue(mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition() > initialSelectedItemPosition);
}
```